# Android studio gradle not downloading

Tags: android, gradle

I have setup my android studio and now I have created a projectbut the gradle is not syncing it all points to me having no internet but I have Internet and when I go to the url manually in my browser in the snapshot attached. Please has anyone encountered this before and I have Internet everything else is opening or does anyone have an alternative url I can use to download the gradle distribution. Thanks

I tried manual download
I tried changing my Internet source all to no avail

Comment: Ensure AS is not in off-line mode (IIRC `compiler -> gradle` or so).